# Replace li Items with divs with classes

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm trying to output the categories of my custom post type but instead of them displaying as li items, I woujld like them each to be a div so I can style them in nice floated boxes...

The code I have is as follows:

```
<?php
    $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('short_courses');

    if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
    {
         foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
         {
             $args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'name',
                  'show_count' => 0,
                  'pad_counts' => 0,
                  'hierarchical' => 1,
                  'taxonomy' => $tax,
                  'title_li' => '',
                  'hide_empty' => FALSE
                );

             $categories = wp_list_categories($args);
                if ( $categories ) {
                    printf( '<div class="sc-cat-items">%s</div>', $categories );
                }

         }
    }
?>
```

Having looked around its of forums, I keep seeing this same answer but this isn't working - its still displaying each category as an li item inside a ul...

My site is here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/short-courses/

I want end up with he categories looking something like this: https://leicestercollege.ac.uk/courses/

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all possible categories, or all categories for a given post?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of all categories inside the custom post type... the site is here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/short-courses/ if it helps :)

Comment: Well, I have the list - I just want to display them as divs so I can style them in boxes - like this here: https://leicestercollege.ac.uk/courses/

Comment: `wp_list_categories` is for generating a fully-formed html list of categories, if you want custom output, that's the wrong function.

Comment: Care to expand on that, Milo? What do I need to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way that works great for me here :)

```
<?php
    $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('short_courses');

    if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
    {
         foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
         {
             $args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'name',
                  'show_count' => 0,
                  'pad_counts' => 0,
                  'hierarchical' => 1,
                  'taxonomy' => $tax,
                  'title_li' => '',
                  'hide_empty' => FALSE
                  );

                $categories = get_categories( $args );
                foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                    echo '<div class="sc-cat-items"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>';
                }

         }
    }
?>
```

If anyone would like to expand on why the original didn't work, please feel free...